# Bootstrap static files not being included in Django template

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Django, and facing issues rendering bootstrap on a django page.

This is my base html,

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Dropbox Web App Prototype</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="jumbotron">
       <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template showcasing the optional theme stylesheet included in Bootstrap. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique by building on or modifying it.</p>
      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The static file is at the same level as the project directory and has the following structure,
[image]

I've also added the following line, to my settings.py file

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

The CSS is not rendering on the home page. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which Django version do you use?

Comment: static file should be under your project folder (ie at the same folder as urls.py and settings.py)

and also make sure that your app is added to your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS list

Comment: @pp_ 1.9.2 is the version

Comment: @JoranBeasley it is right there and I've added the apps to the installed apps list.

Comment: here is an example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18004504/example_static_files.zip

Comment: @Zeus it might be helpful if you describe your full directory structure as a code block

Comment: Have you ran `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASE_DIR` is defined by default to:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Here `__file__` is actually `settings.py`, so `BASE_DIR` is on the parent directory, the one that contains `manage.py`.

It seems your `static` folder is on another level, so just move it to the same level as `manage.py` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an older syntax that's probably doesn't match your version of Django.
In your html file change:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

to

```
{% load static %}
```

Also, replace the single quote with a double quote :

```
"{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
```

to:

```
"{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}"
```

you can see the exact syntax of dealing with static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

**CDN:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Static**

In urls for django runserver:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),]
```

When running from the webserver, you need to config an alias. Nginx example:

```
location  /static { 
    alias /home/username/mysite/static;}
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/static or 127.0.0.1/static? BTW, for bootstrap CDN is OK

Answer (score 1):

In the html
replace  this

```
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

with this

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and check this is in the settings.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: The static tag *is* the preferred way of referencing static files, changing it to use a relative url won't change anything

Comment: true but it looks as though he has the bootstrap folder in a folder called static so he would need to reference that in his href and mine works

Comment: That is taken care of by the relevant `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting (which now uses an array instead of a tuple (although a tuple should still work))

Comment: very well, mine is set up how it was and works perfectly with bootstrap. he hasn't given us a whole heap to go on. and if it fixes it it fixes it. point to note I'm not the only one to use a tuple in their answer.

Comment: SpeedyH30, initially my downvote was for the first part of your answer which wouldn't achieve anything which upon reflection I thought was a bit harsh, however 5 minutes had already passed by this time which meant the only way I could remove my DV was if the post was edited, since django 1.9 uses arrays instead of tuples, I used that as a scapegoat edit to remove it. apologies!

Comment: no problem, nice to see that some people have some decency.

Answer (score 0):

just define additioaly static url in your settings as follow somewhere on the bottom:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and check again if your bootstrap is served

Answer (score 0):

can you paste your BASE_DIR ? Can you set it to: `BASE_DIR to BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: This is how it was from the beginning.

Comment: it is just a guess but how about adding 'vendor' into  <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> so it looks like  <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>