# Django app on Azure getting images from static files but not Bootstrap, Jquery or CSS files

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service, cdn, django-staticfiles, azure-static-web-app

Got a Django app deployed on Azure with this structure:

```
wwwroot
|---Myproject
|---manage.py
|---oryx-manifest.toml
|---hostingstart.html
|---static //Same static folder and same files from myapp 
├── myapp
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   │   │---bootstrap-3.3.7-dist
│   │   │   │--css
│   │   │   │  │--bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   │  js
│   │   │   │  │--bootstrap.min.js
│   │   │---Datatables
│   │   │   │--jQuery-3.3.1
│   │   │   │  │--jquery-3.3.1.js
│   │   │   │  │datatables.js
│   │   │   │  │datatables.css
|   |   |---Images
|   |   |   |--myimage.png
|   |   |   |--myimage2.png
│   └── templates
```

Thing is, when I call statics on my template this way:

```
<script src="{% static 'Datatables/jQuery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{% static 'Datatables/datatables.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Datatables/datatables.css' %}">

<img src="{% static 'Images/myimage.png' %}" align="center"/><br>
```

Images render perfectly, but CDN datatable and css styles not, and browser console throw me this errors:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

And :

```
myappwapp.azurewebsites.net/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/static/Datatables/datatables.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Makes no sense, order of calling scripts on template it´s ok (already tried different orders), also, images are loading fine from the same static folder there, and **if I run it on my local machine everything all works fine**... any idea what´s wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT ////// : settings.py

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   ('myapp', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'static')),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: Try my answer, if not works for you, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to `settings.py`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

**Reason**

It seems your `static` folder in wrong level.

**Related Posts**

[1. Bootstrap static files not being included in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277569/bootstrap-static-files-not-being-included-in-django-template)

[2. BOOTSTRAP // not working despite adding cdn links and reference style link // PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716344/bootstrap-not-working-despite-adding-cdn-links-and-reference-style-link-py)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, I´ve tried your code but got this : ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.....I´ve updated my question with how I´m setting the statics.